# ADFS relying party authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, wif, claims-based-identity, adfs

I have a relying party asp.net webapp and the users are authenticated by a ADFS Security Token Service (STS). Users from 2 domains are part of a security group which is used by the STS to check membership against and issue claims.

Users are getting authenticated as expected when logged in from one domain, but not from another domain. Is there any config settings that should be taken care of?

Any pointers will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Should that be relaying instead of relying in the first sentence?

Comment: @owlstead, No, its relying party, it relies on the STS

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two options.

First (I haven't really tried that) would be to create a two-way trust relationship between your domains. This could (I think) allow your users from both domains to login through your adfs set up on one of the domains.

Second, you could have an extra adfs per domain and then you could create a trust relationship between adfses. This way your users would be prompted which domain they'd like to authenticate/authorize against.